# Xcode- Make Textview continue horizontally forever

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I am trying to make a basic text editor (For a School Project if you are wondering) and I want to make it work with different code. The problem is that I cant get TextView to go on forever horizontally. Similar to Notepad++. I have set it to have the ability scroll horizontally, but I cannot seem to make the text keep going on one line. This is for a Mac OS X application and I am using Xcode 5. Also, on a side note, if you by chance know how to number the rows, I would greatly appreciate that as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Menu option: Xcode->Preferences

From there go to the "Text Editing" tab and check the box for "Line numbers" then in the Indentation subtab uncheck the box for "line wrapping"

To disable word wrap on an NSTextView see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174140/how-to-disable-word-wrap-of-nstextview)

Comment: I am actually new to this... I am sorry.

Comment: Also, that is not what I meant. I want the textview field within the app to show that. Not the text editor in xcode.

Comment: there should be a similar checkbox for the TextView object settings.

Comment: I guess its not that simple. I updated my answer with a link to a better post.