# Can't disable word wrap of NSTextView

Tags: swift, cocoa, word-wrap, nstextview

I have tried the answers in [How to disable word-wrap of NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174140/how-to-disable-word-wrap-of-nstextview)
for half a day but have had no luck. The answers were a bit scattered and confusing really.

I have this code:

```
@IBOutlet var display: NSTextView!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    let LargeNumberForText: CGFloat = 1.0e7
    display.textContainer!.containerSize = NSMakeSize(LargeNumberForText, LargeNumberForText)
    display.textContainer!.widthTracksTextView = false
    display.horizontallyResizable = true
    display.autoresizingMask = [.ViewWidthSizable, .ViewHeightSizable]
}
```

and I have this in the .xib:
[image: NSTextView size settings]

Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was in fact [Premature line wrapping in NSTextView when tabs are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278119/premature-line-wrapping-in-nstextview-when-tabs-are-used) I corrected the issue by employing both the word-wrap code above, and calling this after changing the text:

```
func format() {
    let numStops = 100000;
    let tabInterval = 40;
    var tabStop: NSTextTab

    //attributes for attributed String of TextView

    let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    // This first clears all tab stops, then adds tab stops, at desired intervals...
    paraStyle.tabStops = []
    for cnt in 1...numStops {
        tabStop = NSTextTab(type: .LeftTabStopType, location: CGFloat(tabInterval * cnt))
        paraStyle.addTabStop(tabStop)
    }

    var attrs = [String: AnyObject]()
    attrs.updateValue(paraStyle, forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName)

    display.textStorage!.addAttributes(attrs, range: NSMakeRange(0, display.textStorage!.string.characters.count))
}
```

where `display` is the NSTextView. Subclassing would be more elegant of course.